# How to switch between tty from a shell on a graphic session

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, tty, gui

I would like to know if it's possible to create an alias (on my .zsh_aliases) to launch a command from the graphical session to a tty (does not matter 1 or 6 ...) ?

I tried with for example cmatrix:

```
    alias matrix='sudo chvt 1 && cmatrix -B'
```

and it will open the tty 1 but launch cmatrix on the current shell (on the Xsession).

(I have a zsh shell on Debian 10)

Comment: @Quasímodo thank you very much ! I did not know this program, it suits me, but if possible is there a way that it displays the screen of the terminal in question without doing CTRL + ALT + F1 for example, without doing it manually ?

Comment: Gilles has the answer for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chvt 1` causes vt 1 to become visible, but doesn't affect where subsequent commands run. `cmatrix -B` runs on the same terminal where the original shell is running. If you want to run `cmatrix` on another terminal, you have to let the system know that this is what you want to do.

Use [`openvt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/openvt.1.html) to run a program on a different virtual console. Pass the `-s` option if you also want to make that console visible. `openvt` needs to run as root. If you don't want to run `cmatrix` as root, you'll need to use `su` to lower privileges.

```
sudo openvt -c 1 -s su "$USER" -c 'cmatrix -B'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work for me. I got the following message :
`openvt: Can't open the file : /dev/tty1 : Operation not allowed`
Did you encounterred this ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @shengu You need to be root, that's why the code I posted has `sudo` in front.

Comment: sorry i did not mention that i tested it as root and also with sudo su before

Comment: @shengu I don't see how my version of `openvt` could output this exact message. (Is it a translation back into English? If so, don't do that: always copy-paste error messages.) And I can't think of a reason why `openvt -c 1` wouldn't work as root (assuming you are on a PC or similar hardware with a console).

Comment: `sudo openvt -vf -c 1 -s su "$USER" -e 'ls'`

`openvt: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier : /dev/tty1 : Opération non permise`
Here is the exact output of the command.

Comment: @shengu Ok, so it's “Operation not permitted” (EPERM), not “Access denied” (EACCES). I guess a process that's already running on tty1 (X server maybe) forbids others from also accessing it. Use a different vt.